# VBScript RegEx - Find block of data between a pattern

Tags: regex, vbscript

I am trying to use RegEx to get blocks of data from a multi-line string.

**String to search**

```
***** a.txt
17=xxx
570=N
55=yyy
***** b.TXT
17=XXX
570=Y
55=yyy
*****

***** a.txt
38=10500.000000
711=1
311=0000000006630265
***** b.TXT
38=10500.000000
311=0000000006630265
*****
```

**What I need** - anything between ***** block

```
17=xxx
570=N
55=yyy

17=XXX
570=Y
55=yyy

38=10500.000000
711=1
311=0000000006630265

38=10500.000000
311=0000000006630265
```

**My code so far**

```
Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
objRegEx.Global = True
objRegEx.MultiLine = True
objRegEx.IgnoreCase = True
objRegEx.Pattern = "\*\*\*\*\*(?:.|\n|\r)*?\*\*\*\*\*"
Set strMatches = objRegEx.Execute(objExec.StdOut.ReadAll())
If strMatches.Count > 0 Then
    For Each strMatch In strMatches
        Wscript.Echo strMatch
    Next
End If
Set objRegEx = Nothing
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to turn the last `*` matching part of your consuming pattern into a positive lookahead. Also, it is highly recommendable to get rid of the `(.|\r|\n)*?` since it slows down the matching process, use `[\s\S]*?` instead.

Use

```
\*{5}(?!\s*\*{5}).*[\r\n]+([\s\S]*?)(?=\*{5})
```

and grab the first item in `Submatches`. With `.*[\r\n]+`, I advise to skip the rest of the `*****` starting line.

**Details**:

- `\*{5}` - 5 asterisks
- `(?!\s*\*{5})` - fail the match if there are 0+ whitespaces followed with 5 asterisks
- `.*[\r\n]+` - match the rest of the line with line breaks
- `([\s\S]*?)` - Capturing group 1 (its value is stored in `Submatches` property of the Match object) matching any 0+ chars as few as posssible up to the first....
- `(?=\*{5})` - location followed with 5 asterisks that are not consumed, just their presence is checked.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XnTE4D/1)

If you unroll the regex, it will look uglier, but it is much more efficient:

```
\*{5}(?!\s*\*{5}).*[\r\n]+([^*]*(?:\*(?!\*{4})[^*]*)*)
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ss6Xux/5)

VBS code:

```
Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
objRegEx.Global = True
objRegEx.Pattern = "\*{5}(?!\s*\*{5}).*[\r\n]+([^*]*(?:\*(?!\*{4})[^*]*)*)"
Set strMatches = objRegEx.Execute(objExec.StdOut.ReadAll())
If strMatches.Count > 0 Then
    For Each strMatch In strMatches
        Wscript.Echo strMatch.Submatches(0)
    Next
End If
Set objRegEx = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. Couple of issues with this patter - 1) The headers are also extracted (for e.g. ***** a.txt). I don't need that. 2) It also matches the blank line between ***** & ***** a.txt.

Comment: Ok, the 2) is true, but it is easy to handle with a lookahead (see my updated answer). As for 1), I said you must access the first item in the `strMatch.Submatches(0)`. Note you do not need to set `objRegEx.MultiLine = True`.

Comment: When I am using the second regex, I am also getting ***** at the end which I don't get when I use the first regex.

Comment: There is no way you can have them in the capturing group. See https://regex101.com/r/ss6Xux/5. The `(?:\*(?!\*{4})[^*]*)*` part only matches `*` that are not followed with 4 `*`s.

Comment: Yeah, that was my mistake - apparently there were 2 blank newlines towards the end which was messing it up. I trimmed the string and now it is working. i now just need to work towards removing the headers in each match.

Comment: strMatch.Submatches(0) etc is still showing me the ***** a.txt, ***** b.txt along with the block of text

Comment: Ahh i got it now. Works like a charm

Comment: Great Explanation!

Answer (score 2):

Just capture the sets of consecutive numbered lines

```
Option Explicit

Dim data
    With WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        data = .Exec("fc.exe /n 1.txt 2.txt").StdOut.ReadAll()
    End With 

Dim match
    With New RegExp
        .Pattern = "(?:^[ ]*[0-9].*?$[\r\n]+)+"
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        For Each match in .Execute( data )
            WScript.StdOut.WriteLine "---------------------------------------"
            WScript.StdOut.WriteLine match.Value
        Next 
    End With
```

Comment: It works only if there are no lines not starting with digits and will also match any text before the first `*****` if the lines start with digits. It does not check if the data is in between the asterisks.

Comment: There will never be any line starting with digit in my scenario. And I too am actually parsing the information i get via `fc` (building a vbs solution to match difference between 2 text files).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, You are right, the regexp is completly adapted to the format of the data, but I play with the advantage (sorry) of knowing that the data being processed is the output of a `fc /n` command.