# Regex find match within a string

Tags: regex

I have an example string:

```
Ole Abraham  of XYZ becomes Chief Digital Officer and EVP, Business Development of Warner Music Group.
```

I want all the words from the last occurrence of `of` till `.`.
Result required: `of Warner Music Group.`

I have used the RegEx: `(\bof\b).+\.\s?` 
This is returning the sub-string from the first occurance of `of`:

```
of XYZ becomes Chief Digital Officer and EVP, Business Development of Warner Music Group.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex engines process the string from left to right, thus, the `of` your pattern matches is the first from the left. Then, `.+` matches the whole line to its end, and only backtracks to find `.` (the `\s?` is not important, as it can match an empty string, but will be matched if found right after `.` since `?` is a greedy quantifier).

You may use

```
.*\bof\s+([^.]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lRCY7U/3). The result will be in Group 1. Note that if you must test for the `.` presence in the string, append `\.` to the end of the pattern.

**Details**

- `.*` - will match any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, up to the last occurrence of the subsequent subpatterns
- `\bof` - a whole word `of`
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
- `([^.]+)` - one or more chars other than `.`.

Comment: I am a novice user to Regex but demo is really helpful. Could you please suggest how can I capture the group match only and not the full match.

Comment: @SonuKumar: What is the  regex flavor? What computer language are you using? In almost all cases, you do not need to get the full match, you may access *captures* using appropriate language means.

Comment: am using VB Script

Comment: Then use `match.Submatches(0)` to access that value. See [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42273183/vbscript-regex-find-block-of-data-between-a-pattern/42273297#42273297) for a code snippet.