# Regex with multiple cues: find all shortest options

Tags: python, regex

I have a problem closely related to this question:
[Regex find match within a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44841244/regex-find-match-within-a-string)

In that case the problem is to find `Warner Music Group` instead of `XYZ becomes Chief Digital Officer and EVP, Business Development of Warner Music Group` for

```
Ole Abraham  of XYZ becomes Chief Digital Officer and EVP, Business Development of Warner Music Group.
```

which is solved using `.*\bof\s+([^.]+)`

Now I have a very similar problem, with the difference that I want all matches, and the previous solution returns only one. Here you have my basic setup with the solution above: https://regex101.com/r/bIbFaW/1

The problem is that for the string

```
This is a test with a string with punctuation, and an end. Then test words, and more text. And here whith more text with more punctuation, like that.
```

the pattern `.*\bwith(.*?),` will only get me  `more punctuation` (a good match), missing an earlier option  `punctuation` from the first sentence.

Is it possible to do this or should I approach it differently? For example `with(.*?),` gets all matches, but they are the longer options ( `a string with punctuation` instead of  `punctuation,`). I could then try to find matches within my matches, but doing this at this moment has unrelated overhead which would be nice to avoid if possible.

[image: example text, with colours highlighting different parts of the string]

Comment: Perhaps like this `\bwith\b((?:(?!\bwith\b)[^,])*),` https://regex101.com/r/5Ydb6h/1

Comment: Your first `.*` is greedy. So you could just replace it with `/.*?\bwith (.*?),/gm` : https://regex101.com/r/bIbFaW/2

Comment: The fourth bird this seems to work, it's a bit intimidating but so far it seems to hold to some quick testing. Feel free to write a solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid matching a comma with a negated character class `[^,]` and match `with` followed by matching any character except a comma or matching with again using a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat).

Then match the comma at the end.

```
\bwith\b((?:(?!\bwith\b)[^,])*),
```

- `\bwith\b` Match the word `with`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole part

    - `(?!\bwith\b)[^,]` Match any char except a comma if the current position is not directly followed by the word "with"
  - `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat it
- `)` Close group 1
- `,` Match a comma

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5Ydb6h/1)

Answer (score 1):

**What about if your sentence finishes by a dot? or another punctuation char?**

To make it simple and easier to read, without using regex lookaheads,
which makes it run with more steps, I would propose this start-up:

```
\bwith\s+([^,.]*)/g
```

V1: https://regex101.com/r/kUXu9z/1

- `\b` matches the word boundary to avoid matching "with" in "bandwith" or
  something similar.
- `with` matches the word "with".
- `\s+` because we know that they should be at least one spacing char,
  including possible line feeds or whatever.
- `([^,.]*)` or `([^,.]+)` is the capturing group matching
  any chars which aren't commas or dots. But this list may not be enough as
  you could have "!", "?", ":", etc.

If we add some usual punctuation: https://regex101.com/r/kUXu9z/2

Using Unicode class characters (available in PHP and JavaScript, but with
Python you may need to search if it's available in a lib), we could use the
*punctuation* class of chars `\p{P}` or `\p{Punctuation}` and invert it with
`\P{P}+` in order to match all chars which are not punctuation chars:

```
/\bwith\s+(\P{P}+)/gu
```

V3: https://regex101.com/r/kUXu9z/3

### Edit (as I didn't see the problematic of the multiple "with")

Sorry, I didn't clearly read/understand the problematic of the first
occurrence of "with" which is followed by a second "with" before the
comma.

In this case, we effectively need to use a negative lookahead to
avoid matching a string containing "with" in it:

```
/\bwith\s+(?!\P{P}*\bwith\b)(\P{P}+)/gu
```

I added `(?!\P{P}*\bwith\b)` after the space chars to check that
we don't have some non-punctuation chars followed by the word "with".

V4: https://regex101.com/r/kUXu9z/4

Comment: Note this is not exactly what I need, since the first match is "with a string with punctuation" instead of "punctuation", the shorter option.

Comment: @Pablo Ah, I see! Sorry, I didn't notice that we had twice the word "width" and the last was the one to match. Effectively, in that case, we need to use a negative lookahead.